# SQL function to convert NUMERIC to BYTEA and BYTEA to NUMERIC

Tags: sql, postgresql

In PostgreSQL, how can I convert a `NUMERIC` value to a `BYTEA` value? And `BYTEA` to `NUMERIC`? Using `TEXT` values I can use `CONVERT_TO()` and `CONVERT_FROM()`. Is there anything simmilar? If not, how would it be the SQL function code?

Comment: Do you want to convert the text representation of a number to a bytea ascii string? Or some form of binary data?

Comment: Some form of binary data. If I wanted to do it using the text representation, it will be very easy: CONVERT_TO(numeric_value::TEXT, 'UTF8') and CONVERT_FROM(bytea_value, 'UTF8')::NUMERIC

Comment: There is no way of accessing the internal binary representation of a numeric value (which has a variable length, depending on the value, and can have 131072 digits before the decimal point, and 16383 digits after it. You'd have to develop a function in c to retrieve the internal representation in bytea.

Answer (score 5):

Here are functions tested with PG 11. Note that `numeric2bytea` handles only nonnegative numbers.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bytea2numeric(_b BYTEA) RETURNS NUMERIC AS $$
DECLARE
    _n NUMERIC := 0;
BEGIN
    FOR _i IN 0 .. LENGTH(_b)-1 LOOP
        _n := _n*256+GET_BYTE(_b,_i);
    END LOOP;
    RETURN _n;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL IMMUTABLE STRICT;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION numeric2bytea(_n NUMERIC) RETURNS BYTEA AS $$
DECLARE
    _b BYTEA := '\x';
    _v INTEGER;
BEGIN
    WHILE _n > 0 LOOP
        _v := _n % 256;
        _b := SET_BYTE(('\x00' || _b),0,_v);
        _n := (_n-_v)/256;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN _b;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

Example:

```
=> select bytea2numeric('\xdeadbeef00decafbad00cafebabe');
           bytea2numeric            
------------------------------------
 4516460495214885311638200605653694
(1 row)

=> select numeric2bytea(4516460495214885311638200605653694);
         numeric2bytea          
--------------------------------
 \xdeadbeef00decafbad00cafebabe
(1 row)
```

Answer (score -3):

I think that VARBINARY is used to store in sql for bytea.
so that convert to numeric to byte use the flowing script

```
select CONVERT(VARBINARY,10)
```

and answer will be 0x0000000A
and VARBINARY  to numeric

```
select CONVERT(int,0x0000000A)
```

and answer will be 10

Comment: There is no `varbinary` in Postgres and `convert` does something different in Postgres as well

Comment: What you say does not work. See this: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html

    convert(string bytea, src_encoding name, dest_encoding name)